# some Qframe and other widget just in one *ui files (pyuic4)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

You know you can after working in `Qt Designer` and  converting via `pyuic4 command` to `executable program` or `module`, You can modify your `code` and merge together and build a `complete program`, But i have serious question:

Suppose I have `QMainWindow`, some  `QFrame` and i don't want to save in separately `*ui files`, i need to save in just one `*ui files`, it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save two forms in one .ui file, but I think that you can do this (I did not tried it but it should work): 
save for example one `QDialog` and one `QMainWindow` (`QFrame` can't stand alone-it needs parent widget) in separate .ui files, convert them via `pyuic4` command to two .py files and then join those two files into one .py module (copy data from one to another - copy class and create instance in `__main__`).

That is not very practical when you want to change something in designer , because you'll need to do whole procedure again.